# From which wordpress file i can change this page's layout

Tags: wordpress, video-gallery

I am currently using wordpress for the website development and i want to change this page's formatting which is having url

```
http://www.selfmadesounds.com/dev3/?catid=featured&slg=featured3
```

I need to change this page's formatting such that i can exclude out the extra things from this page.

Comment: You need to find which template is being served for this page. [Have a read of this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page).

Comment: its an wordpress plugin named all-video-gallery so there is no template assignment for this page.

Answer (score 1):

you are probably looking for `category.php`.

If you are a beginner with templating / themes / wp in general, you can simply search for `class="category"` and add a small string INSIDE the div in all of the template files where the search hit, one by one ,  and see which one is the one you look for .

You can insert `<? php echo 'This is my page'; >` or simply insert `XXXXXX`.

but just make sure you are not doing so in `header.php`, `sidebar.php` or `footer.php` - those will in all likelihood will appear on ALL your pages . ( also `functions.php` is to be excluded , but not in all cases ..)

but like others said, you should read the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) about template hierarchy. it can also be any other filename (`custom-loops.php` file, `custom-category-filename.php` etc. depending on theme.

**Edit I**

I think you are mixing a bit of concepts here .

this line :

```
http://www.selfmadesounds.com/dev3/?catid=featured&slg=featured3
```

Is not a `page`, it is a `URL` with get parameters , and it represents a query for `category : Featured` with `Slug : featured3` .

As for itself , it is NOT a `page` , it is a `Query` ( and i suspect that it is a plugin or theme related ). The query later produces , or renders a page .

At any rate , my advice still stands , Put a dummy code inside all the template pages and see which ones is your page .

For the rest - if you will supply more info or code , people could help more .

Comment: there is no such page like that under theme folder

Comment: @user2319553 what page are you talking about  _?

Comment: i am talking about this page http://www.selfmadesounds.com/dev3/?catid=featured&slg=featured1 can you see its url and can help me from where it must be coming like it is having ctegory id in it.

Comment: the `catid` part means `category ID` and the `slg` means `slug` . Read my edit .

Comment: i know what they mean but i am not able to find particular file for that.

Comment: @user2319553 did you try what I wrote ? open all theme files , search for the  `class="category"` , put your string ?

Comment: there is no such file with this text class="category"

Comment: @user2319553  Then either you are showing us the wrong link, OR you are looking in the wrong place .

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the Wordpress [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display), a quick guess would be single.php from the active theme, but there is no way to be sure other than actually searching in the theme

Comment: its not coming from single.php